# Laravel drag and drop does not store in database table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a drag and drop function in my modal form where users are able to drag items from the left to the right, but when saving, it does not store the dropped item in the database. I have made the `name` in the input tag equal to the controller input but still no result. could anyone offer some assistance?

My controller:

```
public function storesurvey(Request $request)
{
    $energy = new Customer();
    $energy->customername = $request->input('customername');
    $energy->rank1 = $request->input('rank1');
    $energy->rank2 = $request->input('rank2');

    $energy->save();

    return redirect('/survey')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```

My View:

```js
< script >
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
// the Ajax Post update 
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "{{ url('Custom-sortable') }}",
  data: {
    order: order,
    _token: token
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.status == "success") {
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
}); <
/script>
```

```css
<style>.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.source-container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  cursor: move;
}

.item p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.source {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 36px
}

.destination-container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.destination {
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-left: 30px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-droppable-active {
  border-color: #bbb;
}

.ui-droppable-hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.destination span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 9px;
  left: -28px;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="source-container">
    <div class="source" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div class="item" value="item" name="rank1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="rank1">
        <p>Item 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="source" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <div class="item" value="item2" name="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
        <p>Item 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='destination-container'>
    <div class="destination" name="rank1" value="rank1" id="rank1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="destination" name="rank2" value="rank2" id="rank2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @RickJames where would I add that?